# Using the tree window in SCID on a subset of games in the database

Tags: opening, software, database, scid

With a database open in SCID, one can use the tree window to explore openings.  Among other things, it shows the frequency of each move that has been played in the current position and how well that move has scored.

Is there a way to combine this with SCID's filter functionality so that the tree window only uses the subset of games selected by the current filter?  For example, this could be used to explore openings based on 2600+ games or games where the opponents are close in rating.

It is possible to do this by creating a copy of the database and then removing all games that are not in the filter, but this is an inconvenient workaround.  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. In the tree window, there is an "All Games" checkbox. Unchecking this will make the tree window use the filtered games instead of all the games.

[image]

Comment: What version of SCID is this?  Mine does not have such a checkbox.

Comment: I have version 4.6.4.

Comment: It seems that scid has this feature but I was actually using scid_vs_pc.

Answer (score 1):

A more practical workaround to go about this in SCID vs. PC is to copy the filter games to the clipbase and open a tree window for the clipbase database. Admittedly it's still inconvenient compared to the functionality in SCID.

Comment: That's slightly better I suppose. However, I've just switched to scid instead. Back when I started using it, I recall that there were some issues with scid that led to me using scid vs pc. However, now scid just seems better than scid vs pc. The interface is nicer as well and there are a few other small features that scid vs pc is missing.